# select the n-1 rows of a query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am usung oracle 11g.
Suppose the following query returns n rows.

```
SELECT t.id,t.from_date,t.price  FROM prices t order by id, date
```

And i want only first n-1 rows from the query.
How can i possibly do that without using inner queries?

Comment: Why don't you want to use inner queries? And "first n-1" rows as ordered by what?

Comment: What would you `ORDER BY` to determine the "first" n-1 rows?

Comment: because the  query i have, already has a lot of logic and does some calculation also. So it is quite slow. I am using orderby already and wanted something like 'limit' in mysql.

Comment: for order by i have edited my question

Comment: possible duplicate of [Limiting returned record from SQL query in Oracle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486452/limiting-returned-record-from-sql-query-in-oracle)

Comment: Seems to duplicate other questions, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/486452/limiting-returned-record-from-sql-query-in-oracle

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT**: Modified based upon additional information added to question.

```
select p.id, p.from_date, p.price
    from (select id, from_date, price, row_number() over (order by id desc) as r from prices) p
    where p.r <> 1
    order by p.id, p.from_date
```