# SQL for Oracle command

Tags: sql, oracle

MYSQL:

```
SELECT * FROM book ORDER BY $sidx $sord LIMIT $start , $limit;
```

How do I turn this into Oracle?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a language translation service. If you are having a specific issue converting to Oracle, we can help with that.

Comment: You might want to consider using the `search` box at the top of the page to avoid downvotes and closes in future.  FWIW, the canonical answer to the question "Oracle equivalent of LIMIT" is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/470542/how-do-i-limit-the-number-of-rows-returned-by-an-oracle-query-after-ordering).  Share and enjoy.

Comment: Thz ppl very thz for so help. And RB everyone realized what he intended, but is more interested in giving this one a perfect ok. Again thanks to those who helped;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `rownum` property, BUT you have to apply it to the result set already ordered AND you need to pass it from the inner query (credit to Bob Jarvis and Daniel Hilgarth: check their explanations and links given in comments as well). It should be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT b.*, rownum as row_num FROM book b ORDER by $sidx $sord)
WHERE row_num BETWEEN $start AND $start + $limit;
```

Comment: -1: rownum is applied after the where clause. See [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns009.htm) for details. Your query will return no rows.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Can you explain how this answer is different from [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/486513/1229023)? And why [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b3cf8/4) actually returns more than 'no' rows?

Comment: I believe that @DanielHilgarth was trying to say that the query should do something like `SELECT * FROM (SELECT b.*, rownum as row_num from book b order by $sidx $sord) where row_num between $start and $start + $limit`. You need to pull the rownum generated by the inner query out as a separate variable to make it visible by the outer query.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: @raina77ow: If you would read the links provided you already would know the answer. Basically: The first row returned from the query has rownum = 1. The second has rownum = 2. If you say `where rownum > 1` there will be no rows returned as you would first need to return one row to have a rownum > 1. Your first link works as it is using rownum LESS THAN 50, i.e. the first 50 rows. Your fiddle works as it uses between **one** and three. Replace **one** with **two** and you will get no results. A bit hard to explain, that's why I linked authorative sources in my last comment.

Comment: @BobJarvis Greatest thanks for both the code AND the explanation. )

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Now I get it. ) Of course, it well explains why the answer linked (with `rownum < $smth`) works, but my will not. Thank you for this explanation.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the oracle syntax, but you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to rank the rows then select those with `rank BETWEEN @start and @limit`:

```
   SELECT *
   FROM 
   (
       select *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID DESC) AS rank
       FROM book
   )
   WHERE rank BETWEEN @start AND @end
   /* OR
   WHERE BETWEEN ((@PageNum - 1) * @PageSize + 1)
     AND (@PageNum * @PageSize)
   /*
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from(
select rownum as row_num, id from t
  )
where row_num between :start and :start+:limit
```

Answer (score 0):

**10g Onwards**

```
WITH CTE AS(SELECT  b.*, Row_Number() OVER(ORDER BY SIDX,SORD) AS Rn FROM BOOK b)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE Rn BETWEEN STARTLIMIT AND ENDLIMIT
```

Comment: please care to mention the reason for down voting. Anything wrong in the query being provided?

Comment: I don't see a downvote on this question..?  (Click on the number between the upvote and downvote arrows to view the vote totals).